# Error using StackNavigator with switching screens

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to make a SignUp/Login screen with a stackNavigator.
But when I try to navigate from the login page to the signup page.

I've tried creating a const that would be the navigate property but I get the same. If I do all my screens in the same file with the stackNavigator I don't get error but this is not really what I want to do.

Here is my Login Screen first (before getting to this screen in index.js I call the Welcome class to check if the user is logged in are not and I return the  if he's not

```
export default class Login extends React.Component{
    render(){

        return( 
          <ScrollView style={{padding : 20}}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>
              Login
            </Text>
            <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Email Address"/>
            <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Password" />
            <View style={{margin : 7}}/>
            <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Signup')}
            >
              <Text> Don't have an account? Click here</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Button
              onPress={this.props.onLoginPress}
              title="Log in"
              color='grey'
              />
          </ScrollView>   
        );
    }
}
```

My sign up screen is pretty empty it only returns a View with a title as of right now 
And finally here's my StackNavigator file

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Welcome: {
      screen : Welcome
  } , 
  Login: {
    screen: Login
  },
  Signup : {
      screen : Signup
  },

},
{
    initialRouteName: "Welcome"
});

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

Where Welcome is the file that checked if user is logged in are not

The error I get is "error undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.navigate')." When I click the  in Login.js

Comment: Did any errors show up? It would be better if you includes a bit more info. Like: what happens when calls navigation.navigate function, any errors that showed up, etc.

Comment: @NanduKkd I added a screenshot of the error but it seems like it's been deleted : https://imgur.com/a/p2n7qLe

Comment: There doesn't seem any error in your code.

Comment: So, you were able to navigate from "Welcome" screen to "Login" screen but navigation from "Login" screen to "Signup" causes error!?

Comment: Any public repo's?

Comment: Hello, it is because I am using 2 different navigator I also have a draw navigator which is correctly configured. I want the user to only be able to navigate from sign in to sign up. This is why I made 2 different navigator. My repository is private but I might be able to send it to you

Comment: my username - Bot-Lover

Comment: Okay I sent you an invitation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checked your repo. Your `welcome` screen first checks if the user is logged in or not and if not logged in, it **renders** the `login` screen. You're not **navigating** from `Welcome` screen to `Login` screen, but **rendering** another Login screen. The problem lies here. I'll give an example:

In your phone, say iPhone X, you downloaded and installed Facebook from the App Store. Then you logged into your account. That means, the Facebook app in your phone is now configured to use your account. Now, if you want to post your photo, you wont be able to do it if you download and install another Facebook app and try to post from there. You will have to use the same old app which is configured to use your account. (Actually you won't be able to download two at a time :P)

In the same way, you should tell the stack navigator to navigate to the stack navigator's `login` screen, not render another `login` screen. The new `login` screen you created won't have the navigation prop, unless you pass one.

But there is another way. You can render the `signup` screen the same way you render your `login` screen. Copy this code to your `Welcome.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import LoginScreen from './LoginScreen';
import SignupScreen from './Signup';
import DrawerNavigator from '../navigation/DrawerNavigator';

const notLoggedIn=0, loggedIn=1, signingUp=2;

export default class Welcome extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            state: notLoggedIn
        }
    }

    render(){
        switch (this.state.state){
            case notLoggedIn:
                return (
                    <LoginScreen
                        onLoginPress={()=>this.setState({state:loggedIn})}
                        onSignUpPress={()=>this.setState({state:signingUp})}
                    />
                );
            case loggedIn:
                return <DrawerNavigator />;
            case signingUp:
                return <SignupScreen />; //Add onBackPress={()=>this.setState({state:notLoggedIn})}} prop here if you want
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your `Login.js`, change onPress prop from `this.props.navigation.navigate('Signup')` to `this.props.onSignUpPress()`.

You won't need the stack navigator now.(You've your own navigator now) So,  instead of using that stack navigator, you can now directly use your `Welcome` screen. Now you can just delete the stacknavigator.js file.

This should work out, I guess.

*Tip: Saw that you have many unused styles and imports in your files. If you're not really going to use them, you can just remove those lines.  That's up to you.*

**EDIT:**

To pass a function into a navigator, you can use the screenProps prop.

Edit your `Welcome.js`:

```
case loggedIn:
  return <DrawerNavigator logout={()=>this.setState({state:notLoggedIn})} />;
```

`DrawerNavigator.js`:

```
...
const DrawerNavigator = createAppContainer(createDrawerNavigator(
  ...
));

export default class navigator extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return <DrawerNavigator screenProps={{logout: this.props.logout}} />
  }
}
```

And inside your `logout.js`, call the function `this.props.screenProps.logout()` from wherever you want.
This should work.

Comment: Oh :o It is working now, yeah I knew the issue was in rendering a screen and not the navigator correctly. Thanks a lot for your help :D. Lastly do you know by any chance if I can add a props in my drawerNavigator to logout the user and get him back to the login screen? I've tried to add the props to the DrawerNavigator but it seems like it does nothing.

Comment: Hello thanks again for your reply, it is working great yeah I did not know about this screenProps thing I tried to do it without and I was not getting any results. Thanks a lot again really helpful!